# DB2 SQL SUM and GROUPING

Tags: sql, db2, sum, grouping

I am having problems with querying and grouping.

I am needing the following output:

```
officr, cbal, sname  
ABC, 500.00, TOM JONES  
ABC, 200.00, SUE JONES  
ABC TOTAL 700.00  

RAR, 100.10, JOE SMITH  
RAR, 200.05,  MILES SMITH  
RAR TOTAL 300.15
```

SQL below produces the error:

> [DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0122 - Column SNAME or expression in SELECT list not valid.

```
SELECT
    lnmast.officr,  SUM(LNMAST.CBAL), lnmast.sname
FROM
    LNMAST
WHERE LNMAST.RATCOD IN (6,7,8) AND STATUS NOT IN ('2','8')
group by lnmast.officr
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` is a POWERFUL tool for grouping/cubing data.  It lets you combine non-aggregated data with aggregated data in one query result.

```
SELECT lnmast.officr,  SUM(LNMAST.CBAL), lnmast.sname
FROM LNMAST
WHERE LNMAST.RATCOD IN (6,7,8) 
  AND STATUS NOT IN ('2','8')
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((lnmast.officr, lnmast.sname),(lnmast.officr))
```

An example from IBM DOCS: [www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/...](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_groupingexamples.html)  :

```
  SELECT WEEK(SALES_DATE) AS WEEK,
         DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE) AS DAY_WEEK,
         SALES_PERSON, SUM(SALES) AS UNITS_SOLD       
  FROM SALES 
  WHERE WEEK(SALES_DATE) = 13
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (WEEK(SALES_DATE), SALES_PERSON),
                           (DAYOFWEEK(SALES_DATE), SALES_PERSON))
  ORDER BY WEEK, DAY_WEEK, SALES_PERSON
```

This results in:

```
  WEEK        DAY_WEEK    SALES_PERSON    UNITS_SOLD 
  ----------- ----------- --------------- -----------
           13           - GOUNOT                   32
           13           - LEE                      33
           13           - LUCCHESSI                 8
            -           6 GOUNOT                   11
            -           6 LEE                      12
            -           6 LUCCHESSI                 4
            -           7 GOUNOT                   21
            -           7 LEE                      21
            -           7 LUCCHESSI                 4
```

Comment: @henryJ had asked why lucchessi had 8 when only 4 were in week 6.  This was due to a bad copy and paste of data on my part from IBM site.  Corrected it by adding lucchessi's 4 on week 7.